# Django QuerySet next date

Tags: django, datetime, django-models

My model has a DateField. If I wish to retrive all data that have a date after today, how will it be constructed? Eg. retreive all field with dates after today and stop at 31st december

`today = datetime.date.today

Object.object.filter(date__day != today)`

or will it be done using exclude?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to do, you should simply be able to filter like this:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
Object.objects.filter(date__gt=today, date__year=today.year)
```

Comment: Yes, except you need to call `datetime.date.today()` - it's a method.